# Can you use a keyword as a parameter?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to use a keyword as a parameter? I wanted to make a method called `BytesToValue()`, the way it would look is like this:

```
public static T BytesToValue<T>(byte[] buffer, T type)
{
    string retType = typeof(T).ToString();

    if (retType.Contains(".Byte"))
    {
        // code here.
    }
    else if (retType.Contains(".Int16"))
    {
       // code here.
    }
    // and so on with all other types.
}
```

I wanted the `T type` parameter to accept just a keyword e.g. `BytesToValue(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 }, float)`, Is there a way to use keywords as parameters? I know the example wont work but is there a way to make it work? If not then what should i do?

Comment: Why even have that parameter? Its a generic method already.  You have to pass the type to call it (i.e `BytesToValue<float>(new byte[])`)

Comment: Oh, didnt know you were able to do that. @maccettura

Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can even drop the second parameter and just use your generic type:

```
public static T BytesToValue<T>(byte[] buffer)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);

    if (type == typeof(byte))
    {
        // code here.
    }
    else if (type == typeof(short))
    {
       // code here.
    }

    // and so on with all other types.
}
```

Or you can let your string comparaisions if you feel like it or even use a switch case with types (C#7).